# Pytest mocking an eval imported function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

Not sure if this is even possible but is there a way to mock an eval imported function?

For example:

a.py

```
import b

def code():
    me = 'ME'
    should_be_changed = eval('b.mock' + me + '()')

    return should_be_changed
```

b.py

```
def mockME():
    return 'Dummy code'
```

test_a.py

```
import a
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_code():
    #with patch('patch mockME somehow?', return_value='mocked code') as mock_mockME:
        assert_me = a.code()
    assert assert_me == 'mocked code'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `monkeypatch` fixture:

```
# test_a.py

def test_code(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('b.mockME', lambda: 'mocked code')
    assert_me = a.code()
    assert assert_me == 'mocked code'
```

Comment: Thanks wim! Exactly what I was looking for! I did not know such a thing existed. Time to go study it up.